# Create a factor variable using the quantiles

Tags: r

I'd like to create a factor variable using the quantiles of an other variable A.

I tried this code :

```
> cut(value, breaks=quantile(value, probs=seq(0,1, by=0.25)),
      include.lowest=TRUE))
```

But it doesn't work because some of the quantiles are the same, so it doesn't know how to cut.

```
>  'breaks' are not unique
```

Example : q1=2 q2=5 q3=5 q4=8

How can I do in this case ? Maybe we can cut randomly in this case

Comment: Maybe `breaks=unique(quantile(...`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to work

```
x=c(2,5,5,8,10)
qnt <- quantile(x,seq(0,1,.25))

cut(x,unique(qnt),include.lowest=TRUE)
# [1] [2,5]  [2,5]  [2,5]  (5,8]  (8,10]
# Levels: [2,5] (5,8] (8,10]
```

*Alternative answer.* If you still want four bins, even when your data do not justify it, there is a way!

```
set.seed(1024)
x <- sample(1:3,101,replace=TRUE)

binx <- rank(x,ties.method="random")%/%(ceiling(length(x)/4)+1)
```

And here you can see the effects.

```
binx_ranges <- by(x,binx,range)
# binx: 0
# [1] 1 1
# ------------------------------------------------------------ 
# binx: 1
# [1] 1 2
# ------------------------------------------------------------ 
# binx: 2
# [1] 2 3
# ------------------------------------------------------------ 
# binx: 3
# [1] 3 3

table(binx,x)
#     x
# binx  1  2  3
#    0 26  0  0
#    1  8 19  0
#    2  0 13 14
#    3  0  0 21
```

Comment: OK, but I need to cut my vector in 5 parts, not in 3.
If two quantiles are equals, it's ok for me if the row is transfert in one or the other quantile interval.

Comment: `cut(x,5)` gives you five parts, though each bin does not have an equal amount of observations; they're just more-or-less equally spaced.

Comment: Maybe you'll like this better: `rank(x)%/%floor(length(x)/5)`?

Comment: Your sequence only splits it into four bins, the quartiles: `seq(0,1, by=0.25)`.